# Building an iOS app for a client with his own developer account for App Store submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I made an app with xCode 4.3 for a client with his own developer account.
Now i need to send him my compiled/binary app (no source code) so he can submit it under his account.

I dont know his bundle ID and neither i have his developer certificate.

Edit: And he will not supply me his developer certificate.

Can it be done?

I searched how this can be done but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Build the IPA as normal, then send it to him along with a copy of the `Info.plist`.  He must then:

- Edit the `Info.plist` file to include his bundle ID.
- Unzip the IPA.
- Replace the `Info.plist` file.
- Re-sign the application using `codesign`.
- Re-zip the IPA.
- Submit it to iTunes Connect manually.

Comment: Thanks, did you try it? had experience with this ?

Comment: Hi, i'm stuck on this step
@Jim "Submit it to iTunes Connect manually."
Can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: You used to be able to upload the binary through the web interface.  If you can't do that any more, use the application loader.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this before was to log in as the client, and submit from your machine. But I guess this depends on the trust level between you

Comment: Yes, but i will still need to re-build the app with the new bundle ID and his certificate.
The problem is that  he will not supply me access to his developer account.

Comment: as I said, this only works if he trusts you to use his account

Answer (score 0):

You need to have his distribution certificate (with private and public keys) and distribution profile.  When you have those, you can create a compiled app for submission to Apple.

Basically, he needs to create the App ID, certificate, and profile and give them to you.  If he cannot do this, you need to sign in to his account for him.

Once he has the compiled app, he can easily submit it using Xcode or Application Loader.

Comment: The certificate is useless without his private key.

Comment: Yes and he will not supply me them.

Answer (score 0):

Build and archive the iOS app with your own certificates, then send the customer the resulting app archive (zipping up the app's archive directory, if needed).  Look here for Xcode's archive files:  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/

In the archive, they can find and edit the app's Info.plist file.

Then the customer can submit the app archive from Xcode's Organizer and using their own developer account.  Xcode should ask them to re-codesign the app with their own Distribution certificates as part of its upload process.