# Issue while uploading app in iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload my app on iTunes connect. Basically I created that app on client behalf and i am using my Apple Developer Account to upload that app.  After uploading, the apple developers rejected my app with the reason :-

Feb 15, 2017 at 3:27 AM
From Apple
0. 10.0 BEFORE YOU SUBMIT: PROGRAM LICENSE AGREEMENT
Hello,

We still found the following rejection, while reviewing your app. Please see more details below.

PLA 1.2

The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name, “H2OPool,” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the H2OPool brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Once created, you cannot change your seller name or company name in iTunes Connect. For assistance with changing your company name or seller name, you will need to contact iTunes Connect through the Contact Us page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**H2OPool** seems to be a registered brand, and you can not use their name. It's just as they told you in the message:

> that reflects the H2OPool brand

You are not owner of the brand and you can not associate your app with the brand.

[Check this thread for your solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722864/ios-apple-developer-member-center-how-to-submit-apps-on-a-clients-behalf)

[You can also check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039155/building-an-ios-app-for-a-client-with-his-own-developer-account-for-app-store-su)

Comment: OK. Should I ask my client to create his own account ? That will be easy i think ?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma If he already has an account , they should be able to add you as a developer : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html , but if he has no account at all, then you have to manage the app for him through your own account (which is a bad idea), and he should really have his own account and app uploaded through it. Don't forget to accept this answer if this helps your question, good luck! Check my updated answer link.

Comment: OK and should I have to change my code somewhere (like :- Bundle ID) ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to create new account for your client. Once created add it to your account as agent. So for their product you will be developer.